# Apache Hue: Timeline stacking

Tags: solr, hue

I am trying to use Hue 4 for timeline stacking - I am visualizing logs, and I'd like to see number of logged messages in time by *host*. From Hue demo, I know its possible. But in my case, the stacking simply does not work.

The underlying field in Solr has (in my case) this schema

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true"/>
```

Previously we had few problems with other widgets (disabled counter, timeline as a whole) and in both cases Hue was expecting some exact Solr data format, so I suppose this might the same case.

[image]

---

Debug: getTimeline call returns the following message:

```
{status: -1, message: "list index out of range"}
```

Console does not contain any errors, nor server error.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, and this issue will be fixed in https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-7429.